# É possivel saber o motivo de terem deletado/removido os meus comentários de uma postagem?

Tags: debate, suporte, comentários

É possível saber o motivo de terem deletado/removido os meus comentários de uma postagem?

Existem comentários que claro que poderiam causar algum desconforto, mas tem comentários meus que sumiram de postagens, o qual ao meu ver eram pertinentes ao entendimento da "pergunta" ou "esclarecimento" de uma resposta, porém foram removidos. Aconteceu acredito que 3 vezes comigo, claro que tive outros comentários removidos, mas realmente estes "outros" não agregavam nada ao foco da postagem, porém estes "3" casos isolados que me refiro ajudavam a esclarecer o que realmente o autor da postagem queria, eu não me lembro de todos, porém existe esta pergunta:

- [‘itoa’ não é reconhecido](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/55915/3635)

Eu fiz alguns comentários que até aonde me lembro não foram ofensivos e só tinham o intuito de instruir o autor da pergunta.

Eu não sei se foi uma *flag* ou um moderador, mas de qualquer forma eu gostaria de saber se é possível ver ao menos os **meus** comentários deletados e saber o motivo (independente da questão acima citada).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Dos seus comentários naquela pergunta, alguns foram removidos pelos moderadores♦ (que podem excluir comentários e ver comentários excluídos), e outros constam como excluídos por você mesmo.

O negócio com os comentários em geral é o seguinte: eles são considerados descartáveis, e os moderadores não têm muito pudor em excluí-los se achar que estão causando muito ruído. Naquela pergunta, os comentários buscavam esclarecer alguns pontos, possivelmente para evitar o fechamento da pergunta ou permitir sua reabertura. Com as diversas edições, o fechamento e a reabertura, eles foram considerados obsoletos pelo moderador que cuidou do caso.

Comment: Não, eu posso ver mas não sei se posso te mostrar. O motivo eu não sei, teria de falar com quem apagou (olhei melhor agora, realmente tem outros excluídos por moderadores). Mas por acaso você se refere a um que recomendava aprender minimamente a linguagem antes de continuar?

Comment: Guilherme, se quiser me dizer qual era o comentário que você tem na cabeça, eu posso procurar (moderadores podem ver uma lista de todos os comentários, mesmo excluídos, por usuário). Se quiser, podemos falar disso num chat privado.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento pode ser que esse tópico lhe ajude (ou não): [Encontrar comentário feito](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2261/3117)

Comment: Realmente eu não me lembro, eu acreditava ser nesta postagem, era algo como "deve informar a biblioteca que está usando pois não é possivel ajudar sem detalhes", porém isto acho que é muito vago para encontrar algo, mas fico muito grato pela sua dedicação, não precisa se preocupar, só queria realmente saber se poderíamos consultar nossos próprios comentários. Irei considerar o seu ponto de esclarecimento isto "comentários são descartáveis". Obrigado.

Comment: @bfavaretto só outra duvida moderadores com ♦ ou usuários com 20k de pontos podem ver? O simbolo ajuda a diferenciar :)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Só os moderadores♦