# É possível haver uma conexão bidirecional com relação a uma pergunta e seus comentários?

Tags: suporte, perguntas, chat

Estou observando que algumas perguntas podem vir a gerar um debate, e julgo os comentários não serem o melhor lugar para debates muito extensos, então pensei se conectar a um chat especifico não seria a melhor opção.

É possível haver uma conexão bidirecional com relação a uma pergunta e seus comentários?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do meu ponto de vista se a *pergunta* em si gera um debate e não o entendimento do autor (quero dizer que se a própria pergunta em si da maneira que foi escrita gera o debate) então ela deve ser fechada nas seguintes possíveis situações:

- **amplo demais**

  > Ou há muitas respostas possíveis ou boas respostas seriam muito longas para este formato. Acrescente detalhes para reduzir o conjunto de respostas ou isole uma questão que possa ser respondida em poucos parágrafos.
- **principalmente baseadas em opiniões**

  > Várias perguntas boas geram algum grau de opinião com base na experiência de especialistas, mas as respostas a esta pergunta tenderão a ser quase que completamente baseadas em opiniões e não em fatos, referências ou experiência específica.

Se o autor da pergunta está com dificuldade de entender uma resposta e isto está gerando o debate (veja que nesta situação não é a pergunta, mas sim o entendimento de uma das partes) então é possível criar uma sala de *chat/bate-papo*, este é um link que aparece automaticamente após uma quantidade de comentários postados por ambas as parte:

[image: mover comentários para o bate-papo]

Eeste chat fica *vinculado* pelo próprio comentário, mas pode perder este vinculo (Como disse o [@bfavaretto](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3815/3635) comentários são descartáveis e provavelmente o chat também é, ou seja eles só servem para resolver problemas de "entendimento")