# Sobre a política de revisões/edições

Tags: debate, tags, filas-de-análise, edições-sugeridas

Venho questionar a politica de edições, nesse caso foram negadas quatro edições minhas, gostaria de clarificar se realmente esse é o **caminho** a seguir.

**Como utilizar dll em Java**
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/36450

 Nessa edição consolidei a questão do usuário que não soube se explicar bem, tomei o cuidado de olhar suas repostas pra entender melhor seu objetivo, além disso adicionei tags referente as APIs necessárias a sua implementação. Pode ser observado que esse fato gerou até uma resposta equivocada.

**Na analise foi informado que:**

> Esta edição **altera o sentido ou propósito inicial do post**. Mesmo
>   edições substanciais devem procurar preservar os objetivos originais
>   do auto.

**Descordo completamente**, a pergunta se manteve de difícil entendimento, eu não criei ou adicionei nenhuma informação e ao final ela continuou complicada pra ser entendida, encontrada (remoção das tags JNI e JNA) e possivelmente reutilizada por outros no futuro.

**Sobre a adição de tags** 
Nas edições abaixo meu objetivo foi adicionar tags relevantes a questão, acredito que elas são cruciais, pelo fato de aumentarem a relevância do conteúdo, principalmente a Search Engines além de ser uma forma de classificação muito util quando está buscando assuntos muito específicos e as vezes não tão claramente linkados, por muitas vezes no próprio StackOverflow me ajudou com isso informando questões relacionadas ou em uma busca por tag.

**Qual a diferença entre anotação no método e anotação no atributo**
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/36782
Nessa recebi uma aprovação e duas negações, acho que a melhoria das tags traz relevância a questão e descordo **completamente** da posição do revisor:

> Esta edição **não faz** a publicação mais fácil de ser lida, **mais fácil de
>   ser encontrada**, **mais precisa** ou mais acessível. As mudanças são
>   completamente supérfluas ou de fato prejudicam a legibilidade.

**Forma correta de checagem de NULL do Scala no Java**
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/36448
Nessa sugestão de edição adicionei duas tags que são muito relevantes para o contexto da questão do usuário, claramente o revisor não se atentou (ou minimamente se esforçou) para esse fato. Optional é uma API do java 8 claramente em uma busca pela tag, traria respostas relevantes em relação a implementações e seus paralelos, como abordado na questão e aplicado em Scala. Mas a inclusão foi negada com o argumento:

> Esta edição **adiciona tags que não ajudam a definir o assunto da
>   pergunta**. As tags devem ajudar a descrever sobre o **que se trata a
>   pergunta**, e não somente o que ela contém.

> Esta edição não faz a publicação mais fácil de ser lida, **mais fácil de
>   ser encontrada**, mais precisa ou mais acessível. **As mudanças são
>   completamente supérfluas** ou de fato prejudicam a legibilidade.

**Descobrindo o SQL de um ResultSet**
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/36783 
Nessa claramente os revisores não tomaram a atenção de ler os comentários da questão feitas pelo o próprio autor, e rejeitaram uma tag crucial ao comportamento da API e consequentemente quanto a solução do problema. O autor faz uma citação clara ao [jaybird](http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/jdbc-driver/) (driver jdbc do firebird) em uma resposta que não traz resultado, explicando que esse pode ser o motivo. Mais uma vez os revisores tiveram a posição:

> Esta **edição altera o sentido ou propósito inicial do post**. Mesmo
>   edições substanciais devem procurar **preservar os objetivos originais
>   do autor**.

> **Não tem sinal** algum na postagem que isto se trata de **firebird**.

Comment: Então *Não tem sinal algum na postagem que isto se trata de firebird.*, mas tinha nos comentários, ou seja não tem na postagem e não tem na edição. Ninguém é obrigado a abrir pergunta por pergunta e ler todos comentários antes de aprovar uma edição. Existe o campo **"Resumo da Edição"** que deve conter estes tipos de detalhes.

Comment: O Guilherme já deu uma explicação muito detalhada, mas queria ressaltar algo que (para mim) conta na hora de fazer revisões (no SOen tenho rep pra isso). Nas edições 3 e 4, existem melhorias que poderiam ser feitas no texto da pergunta e não foram feitas. Ao meu ver, ao editar uma pergunta, o editor deve também corrigir problemas no texto, mesmo que o objetivo principal seja atualizar tags.

Comment: Passei por isso duas vezes ao tentar editar uma [resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/36967) sua Reginaldo, como o Guilherme disse... Nesses casos acho que é mais prudente informar o autor para que ele mesmo a edite.

Comment: @Florida temos muitos usuarios novos, que não estão acostumados com esse modelo, muitas vezes a questão fica incompleta e até errada e perde a sua função principal a longo prazo, que é ajudar os outros. Concordo que com alguns pontos, como, pode ser tendencioso acatar uma edição sem escrutinar melhor o caso quando ela é originada por quem respondeu a questão.

Comment: Reginaldo Soares sobre você ter chegado a **uma** solução não quer dizer que deve adicionar tags que podem limitar a pergunta a receber novas respostas futuramente com soluções diferentes, acho que talvez não esteja entendendo este ponto, quero dizer se a edição for pertinente a pergunta, ok editar, se ela for mais pertinente a se adequar a uma "única resposta", então está errado. O que o @Florida disse é o correto e torno a dizer, as tags devem ser relevantes ao problema e não as "soluções" já encontradas para que não limite no futuro respostas novas com soluções diferentes.

Comment: @ReginaldoSoares aproveita que você gosta de melhorar as perguntas e veja isto http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1084/101. É só uma das coisas que você acha que pode estar melhorando mas pode estar piorando, mesmo sem perceber. E aí algumas pessoas d**i**scordam da sua edição.

Comment: @bigown obrigado pelo link, aprimoramento constante é meu objetivo,  obrigado pela dica sutil quanto ao meu descuido ao d**e**scordar da forma que vocês revisam edições, por esse tópico me dou por satisfeito, apesar de ter sentido o corporativismo da sua parte, minha intenção foi realmente ajudar, e não esqueça, [be nice!](http://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice)

Comment: Ah, legal, eu sou corporativista? Acho que você não está percebendo o que você está fazendo aqui. Ou talvez não entenda o termo. Mas se acha que sou mesmo, você pode mostrar como.

Comment: @bigown eu também não entendi. Reginaldo poderia explicar o que dizer?

Answer (score 7):

*Fui eu quem rejeitou todas*, não que outras pessoas não tenham rejeitado, mas eu participei de todas rejeições, portanto acho que posso responder e acredito que irão concordar.

## Sobre a edição da pergunta 1 e 2

> 1. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/36450
> 2. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/36448

Você usou as tags para referenciar a solução, mesmo que não intencionalmente, o que eu acho errado, as tags devem ser para referenciar o problema da pergunta, lembre-se uma pergunta pode ter várias respostas e cada resposta pode ser uma solução totalmente diferente da outra. Então as tags devem ser usadas para indicar o problema e não as soluções nas respostas.

## Sobre a edição da pergunta 3

> 3. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/36448

Você disse:

> Nessa claramente os revisores não tomaram a atenção de ler os comentários da questão feitas pelo o próprio autor

Eu discordo, não foi por falta de atenção, o problema é que ninguém é obrigado a ler todos comentários para entender o motivo da edição, *se foi você quem editou* então *você deve explicar* no campo **"Resumo da Edição"** o motivo da edição (o que não foi feito), por exemplo você poderia ter adicionado o link do comentário do autor ou ter até explicado que o autor comentou isto, mas a única coisa escrita foi:

> Comentário: adicionando tags relevantes a questão

Note que comentários são descartáveis, como dito pelo [@bfavareto](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3815/3635), o correto era você orientar o autor a editar e adicionar mais detalhes do problema, não deve-se usar os comentários para adicionar detalhes do problema se isto for pertinente a pergunta.

Somo uma comunidade, se quer editar algo, proponha detalhamento do motivo para facilitar o entendimento de todos.

---

### Detalhamento sobre os problemas das edições

- [**Pergunta 1**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/36450)

  Rejeitei pois a pergunta foi praticamente reescrita, o texto ficou quase que completamente diferente, claro que entendo que você compreendeu o problema dele e até deu a resposta correta, mas a sua **"solução"** não deve fazer parte da pergunta.

  Quero dizer quando adicionou adicionou as tags [jni](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jni) e [jna](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jna), praticamente você já colocou parte da resposta na pergunta (algo que o autor não tinha ideia), ou seja está **errado**.
- [**Pergunta 2**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/36448)

  Praticamente a mesma situação da primeira pergunta, você adicionou a tag [java-8](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-8), mas quem disse que o problema só se aplica ao [java8](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java8)? Isto não faz sentido algum. Ao meu ver você aplicou a tag na edição com o sentido da sua RESPOSTA e não da pergunta, ou seja está **errado**.

  As edições as perguntas na pergunta 1 e 2 foram pra favorecer (claro que não intencionalmente) a suas respostas, o que não tem sentido, pois podem aparecer posteriormente respostas que as soluções propostas sejam totalmente diferentes das suas e não sejam vinculadas as *tags* sugeridas na edição.
- [**Pergunta 3**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/36448)

  Em nenhuma parte **da PERGUNTA** o autor falou de *FIREBIRD*, ou seja se o autor adicionou tal detalhe no comentário de alguma postagem e os usuários com capacidade de aprovar e rejeitar edições não são obrigados a abrir *pergunta por pergunta* pra procurar isto em todos comentários. Você deve usar o campo **"Resumo da Edição"** na edição para mencionar detalhes como o tal comentário, algo como:

  - > O autor comentou o seguinte ...

    ou
  - > O autor comentou o seguinte http://...

---

### Como detalhar as edições

Ao meu ver as edições foram feitas sem detalhamento e ou tentando favorecer uma resposta especifica e apenas a edição da última pergunta poderia ser *justificável* **SE VOCÊ** tivesse adicionado detalhes no campo **"Resumo da Edição"** sobre o *jaybird*:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Espero que não leve a mal a minha sinceridade e assim poderá fazer um bom trabalho com as edições assim como tem feito com as boas respostas. Parabéns pelas respostas.

Comment: Guilherme, continuo discordando (desse padrão) de analise e revisão, primeiramente existem dois revisores para se fazer um double check, o que vejo é que muitas vezes existem "uma pressa" em analisar rapidamente as questões sem considerar o que é e realmente importante e relevante o objetivo final é manter um base de informação rica e acessível e não em seguir regras que não fazem sentido. Na própria referencia (HelpCenter do SO) as informações são claras quanto a isso.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/editing --> 1 -- To clarify the meaning of the post (without changing that meaning)
2 --To include additional information only found in comments, so all of the information relevant to the post is contained in one place

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging --> You should re-tag questions when:
You are adding valuable information to the question by doing so
You are replacing obscure or difficult to understand tags with well-known and popular tags that are appropriate for the question.

Comment: Finalizando não tenho intenção de criar tags para favorecer minhas repostas (como você afirmou), isso seria subestimar a inteligência da plataforma e de todos que atuam aqui, a partir do momento que o faço (respostas ou edições) coloco (meu conhecimento) a prova de questionamento a qualquer um e entendo que pode ser alterado futuramente ou questionado, isso faz parte processo de evolução.

Comment: Manter uma questão mal formulada ou não adicionar uma tag (que adiciona relevância e facilita que ela seja futuramente encontrada) usando de uma avaliação superficial e subjetiva é algo que prejudica a essência dessa plataforma.

Comment: @ReginaldoSoares Não disse que fez isto de proposito *"intenção de criar tags para favorecer minhas repostas"*, eu disse que fez isto sem pensar que podem haver soluções diferentes da sua resposta. Portanto a pergunta 1 e 2 não devem ter tais tags adicionadas.

Comment: A pergunta 3 eu concordo com a tag, o que eu não concordo é com você não ter usado o campo **"Resumo da Edição"** apropriadamente. @ReginaldoSoares

Comment: @ReginaldoSoares Não leve a mal, vejo que tem colaborado bastante com a comunidade e sempre tem boas respostas, só tenho a lhe dar os parabéns por isto. Apenas está errado no caso das edições... Note que editei a resposta para: *foram pra favorecer (claro que não intencionalmente) a suas respostas, o que não tem sentido, pois podem aparecer posteriormente respostas que as soluções propostas sejam totalmente diferentes das suas e não sejam vinculadas as tags sugeridas na edição.*

Comment: Nesse caso sugere-se uma outra alteração, e será mantido um ciclo de vida, com a evolução da questão-resposta e tudo mais, muitas questões podem estar em ciclo de analise e evolução constante, faz parte dessa evolução ponderar se uma nova TAG é relevante ou não, mas ponderar isso não é simplesmente recusa-las sumariamente, da mesma forma que um editor deve ter cuidado ao editar um revisor deve ter cuidado ao revisar.

Comment: não leve tom como pessoal, não estou bravo ou procurando briga, só quero debater o que seria melhor pra uma plataforma que me ajuda muito, espero poder aplicar melhorias nela pra ajudar os outros e não simplesmente somar pontos.

Comment: **Pergunta 1 e 2:** Não concordo com a adição das tags nas perguntas 1 e 2, elas devem ficar abertas para outras respostas com soluções diferentes, adicionar estas tags "fecharia" para outras soluções, a pergunta não deve "evoluir", o que deve evoluir são as respostas e podem haver respostas diferentes com soluções diferentes. Este não é o foco das tags, o foco das tags é para o problema que o autor enfrenta, independente da solução. @ReginaldoSoares

Comment: **Pergunta 3:** A pergunta 3 é a unica que concordo com a tag, só rejeitei devido ao autor não ter adicionado na pergunta e ninguém é obrigado abrir pergunta por pergunta na "FILA DE ANALISE" e o campo "Resumo da Edição" deveria conter o link do comentário ou mencionar que o autor comentou sobre o firebird. @ReginaldoSoares

Comment: @ReginaldoSoares Eu sei que estamos apenas debatendo, não se preocupe.